# Sha hashing in Java

Tags: java, hash, sha1

So I'm working on a project where I need to hash a users password before I store it (For a login prompt). The code that actually hashes the textworks fine, but I am trying to use it form another class. The problem is I get the following error and I don't know what it means.

```
1 error found:
File: /Users/justin/Desktop/Culminating Java/login.java  [line: 10]
Error: /Users/justin/Desktop/Culminating Java/login.java:10: unreported exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Here is the code for hashing

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashTextTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
     */
    public static void hasher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println(sha1(login.InputPassword));
        System.out.println(sha1("password"));
    }

    static String sha1(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to use it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class login{
  public static String InputPassword = "";
  public static void main (String args[]){

 HashTextTest myhasher = new HashTextTest();

    myhasher.hasher();


} 
}
```

Comment: in main, `myhasher.hasher()` might throw the exception `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, so you must either catch it there or use a throws clause in the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the output carefully it says:

Error: /Users/justin/Desktop/Culminating Java/login.java:10: unreported exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; **must be caught or declared to be thrown**

It means it is a checked exception at compile time and you must handle it in `login.java`. Either wrap a try,catch around the call to `myhasher.hasher();` and catch the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    HashTextTest myhasher = new HashTextTest();
    try {
        myhasher.hasher();
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or add a `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException` to the main method like so:-

`public static void main (String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException`